# Неактивны товары в корзине Django

Tags: python, django, интернет-магазин

```
    class CartProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Покупатель', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', verbose_name='Корзина', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_products')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Общая цена', default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Продукт: {} (для корзины)'.format(self.content_object.title)

class Cart(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Владелец корзины', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(CartProduct, blank=True, related_name='related_cart', symmetrical=True)
    total_products = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Общая цена')
    in_order = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_anonymous_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Есть две модели. Cart и CartProduct.

И класс в файле View для добавления товара в корзину.

```
class AddToCartView(View):


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ct_model, product_slug = kwargs.get('ct_model'), kwargs.get('slug')
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart = Cart.objects.get(owner=customer, in_order=False)
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        product = content_type.model_class().objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.create(
            user=cart.owner, cart=cart, content_object=product, final_price=product.price

        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

Всё работает, товар добавляется, НО по умолчанию он неактивен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е товар не отображается в корзине, пока я его вручную через админку не выделю кликом мышки.
Почитал про модель ManyToMany, никаких аргументов чтобы это исправить там нет. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри у тебя две модели `Cart` и `CartProduct` и они связаны между собой двумя способами:
полем `CartProduct.cart` и полем `Cart.products`

Когда ты создаешь форму на основе `CartProduct`, джанго автоматически показывает привязку на основе `Cart.products`
а в твоем view ты когда создаешь объекты `Cart` и `CartProduct` ты не заносишь в `Cart.products` ни одного элемента, поэтому в форме у тебя эти элементы и не выделяются. Это можно исправить добавив перед `return` следующий код

```
cart.products.add(cart_product)
cart.save()
```

Но, на мой взгляд, у тебя модели избыточны и тебе не нужны обе привязки одновременно и в том и в другом классе. Вполне достаточно обойтись чем-то одним.
Если ты уберешь привязку `CartProduct.cart` то, в принципе все будет работать как сейчас с ней.
Если же ты хочешь оставить привязку через `CartProduct.cart` убрав `Cart.products`, тогда тебе нужно будет усложнять форму для редактирования корзины. Нужно, что бы помимо объектов формы в ней отображались еще связанные объекты из `Cart`
Для админки ты это можешь сделать через `inline` классы (подробней https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

```
class CartProductAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CartProduct
    
    
class CartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Cart
    inlines = [CartProductAdmin]
```

при создании своих форм вне админки, тебе понадобится использовать formset (подробней https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets)